# Why is getting a COM+ component through C# interop taking so long?

Tags: c#, service, interop, com+

I use the following library which references my COM+ component:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ServiceLib
{
    [ClassInterface(0)]
    [Guid("9DA56255-697A-11D4-935C-00105AD43C9D")]
    [TypeLibType(2)]
    public class ServiceClass : IServiceManager, ServiceManager
    {
        public ServiceClass();
        ...
    }
}
```

In my code, I reference it like so:

`ServiceClass serviceClass = new ServiceLib.ServiceClass();`

However, it can take up to 5 minutes to get the object. My COM+ components are service wrappers, wrapped around windows services. So, basically, when something does create a COM+ reference I'd expect the windows service to start up for it, but it doesn't. Neither does any .exe process associated with it. So literally, nothing as far as I can tell is happening on my system for 5 minutes until the line above returns with the COM+ object.

Comment: Delays that long are usually associated with network timeouts.  Use the trouble-shooting techniques demonstrated in [Mark Russinovich's blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/) to find the underlying reason.

Comment: @HansPassant Its all local.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue was the underlying process for the COM+ component died early on, and there wasn't enough time to catch it on my end (**to check, use Event Viewer in Windows**). The reason why it died, is that multiple processes were trying to create a reference to it, and the constructor failed due to synchronization issues around the fact that multiple processes were trying to get it!

Edit: In a separate console app I made to test the issue, I create a reference to the component in three new threads, and [the odd time I do see this issue that is a known problem around COM+, related to multiple user accounts creating too many COM+ references](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870655).

**Edit again: I managed to solve all my problems by issuing a service start on my windows service that hosts a COM+ object, BEFORE I create any references to it.**

Final edit: The real problem was that the COM+ object wasn't creating a proper singleton of itself and it was producing a race condition on AtlAdvise calls...the solution above works because it ensures no race condition is produced. Normally I would go with creating thread safe code. But alas, it's not my problem since I'm using someone else's APIs.